# Story/novel about a planet where people interact only through screens

Tags: story-identification

I read story about a planet where no one actually touches each other, but view everything through screens. There was a murder on this planet and Earth sent a medical examiner to solve the crime, but people were freaked out because he actually wanted to meet in person. Any ideas?.. I read this long before cell phones and laptops, so it resonates with me now.

Comment: A similar story where nobody actually touches each other and just views each other through screens is *The Machine Stops* by EM Forster. There's no murder involved, but if you enjoyed the story you're looking for, you might enjoy that one too.

Comment: Reminds me of the [Buy-N-Large's starliner](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/BNL_Starliner) in [WALL-E](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224963/story-about-the-scientists-in-mars-that-are-less-cooperative-than-the-scientists (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 51):

I believe this is [The Naked Sun](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30016.The_Naked_Sun) by Isaac Asimov.

> A millennium into the future, two advancements have altered the course
>   of human history:  the colonization of the Galaxy and the creation of
>   the positronic brain.  On the beautiful Outer World planet of Solaria,
>   a handful of human colonists lead a hermit-like existence, their every
>   need attended to by their faithful robot servants.  To this strange
>   and provocative planet comes Detective Elijah Baley, sent from the
>   streets of New York with his positronic partner, the robot R. Daneel
>   Olivaw, to solve an incredible murder that has rocked Solaria to its
>   foundations.
>
> The victim had been so reclusive that he appeared to his associates
>   only through holographic projection.  Yet someone had gotten close
>   enough to bludgeon him to death while robots looked on.  Now Baley and
>   Olivaw are faced with two clear impossibilities:  Either the Solarian
>   was killed by one of his robots--unthinkable under the laws of
>   Robotics--or he was killed by the woman who loved him so much that she
>   never came into his presence!

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like [The Naked Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun) by Isaac Asimov. However the protagonist was a detective, not a medical examiner.